# Removing Non Duplicate Keys from Two Dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have two dictionaries in Swift with few similar values which are in dynamic mode:

```
dict1 = ["a1":"value 1", "b1":"value2", "c1":"value 3"]
dict2 = ["b1": "value2", "d1": "value4"]
```

If I want to compare these two dictionaries and want to extract only the matching keys even nested, how do I about to do that?

Comment: The term for this is "set intersection", btw.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the common keys with the value in one of them :

```
let intersectionDict = dict1.filter { dict2.keys.contains($0.key) }
//Or
let intersectionDict2 = dict2.filter { dict1.keys.contains($0.key) }
```

If you want the values to match too:

```
let intersectionDict3 = dict1.filter { dict2[$0.key] == $0.value }
```

And the result is:

```
print(intersectionDict3)  //["b1": "value2"]
```

Comment: You can actually speed this up by writing a function that iterates over the smaller of the two dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

As others have shown, you can do this using a `filter` statement. You can make it even quicker by always filtering the smaller of the two dicts, improving the time complexity from `O(dict1.size)` to `O(min(dict1.size, dict2.size)`.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func intersectingByKeys(with other: Dictionary) -> Dictionary {
        let (smallerDict, largerDict) = (self.count < other.count) ? (self, other) : (other, self)
        return smallerDict.filter { key, _ in largerDict.keys.contains(key) }
    }
}

let dict1 = ["a1":"value 1", "b1":"value2", "c1":"value 3"]
let dict2 = ["b1": "value2", "d1": "value4"]

print(dict1.intersectingByKeys(with: dict2))
```

Comment: `keys.contains(someKey)` is O(n); `dict[someKey] != nil` would be O(1).

Comment: @JoshCaswell [Not anymore.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0154-dictionary-key-and-value-collections.md#introduction) Although the implementation of [Dictionary.Keys](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2d0fe537242f6ffb4cb5cae0367c9c8affa265be/stdlib/public/core/Dictionary.swift#L1282-L1407) doesn't seem to have a custom overload of `contains(_:)`

Comment: @Alexander Just quick concern, would this work for nested keys as well?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about that proposal. But if there's no customization, then I don't see how it [can avoid still being O(n)](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2d0fe537242f6ffb4cb5cae0367c9c8affa265be/stdlib/public/core/SequenceAlgorithms.swift#L514-L518)

Comment: @kforkarim Nope. You would need to write your own recursive logic.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yeah, if there's no overload somewhere somehow, then it would fall back to that generic linear search. I was hoping to see an overload which forwards the call onto the wrapped dictionary. I'll ask the Swift forums.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Let's see how this goes. https://forums.swift.org/t/does-dictionary-keys-contains-have-o-1-time-complexity/21647

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Set` from the keys of one of the dictionaries and call `intersection` on the `Set` with the keys of the other dictionary.

```
let matchingKeys = Set(dict1.keys).intersection(dict2.keys) // {"b1"}
```